# Save png to outputstream truncated

Tags: c#, browser, iis-7.5

Hope this not a duplicate...

Suppose I have a image in png format, around 300kb in size, and I send it to the client from a aspx file like this:

```
Bitmap img = new Bitmap(filepath);
using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    img.save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);

    Response.ContenType="image/png";
    ms.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
}
img.Dispose();
```

In client side javascript, it's simply:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = xxx.aspx?param=semething;
```

This usually works... But occasionally the response seems to be cut short. Chrome would wait for the request until it times out. In firebug, in the Images view under the Net tab, the request actually shows something like:

```
Get xxx.aspx?param=something   hostUrl   0(14.7mb) 127.0.0.1:80
```

That 14.7mb looks pretty bizzare... After it seemingly timed out, firebug would actually show the entire loaded image though.. so IIS seemes to have sent out everything in this case...

In all cases, the headers are correctly showing contentType and content-Length.
There are times that the request just won't end until I close the browser or pull the image from the webpage. Then I can find IIS sending error message to the event log saying that the remote host closed the connection.

I just can't seem to pin point the problem...

- Edit -

Changed to simply do a Response.TransmitFile(filePath), but the problem is still there.
At least in chrome I think the request is eventually terminated by the browser after 90 seconds. IIS did not log any error... 
Looks like IIS think that it had done all it had to do.. but something went missing on the way to the browser... on local machine.

I'll bring the system to another machine and test it out later...
And also try changing to .ashx later...

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what other code there running but you need to make sure clear your response first before you write anything into it:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ClearContent();
Response.ClearHeaders();
```

Also I highly recommend you use **Response.TransmitFile** instead of read file into memory, read it and then write into the output stream could be really memory consuming.

**EDIT**

Also if you could change to use .ashx instead .aspx it could be faster.

Comment: Great. I'll give it a shot and test it a bit first.

Comment: Well... I tried to use Response.TransmitFile and also clear the response contents before hand. But the problem persists.
I'll try making a .ashx when I have more time on my hand and see how it goes..

Comment: Do you have any further code not posted here after the file reading?

Comment: Nope.. originally that's the end of the function. With the use of Response.TransmitFile.. transmitfile is the last line of code to run.

Comment: Maybe try use Response.End() at the end of this function see if that help

Comment: I did that too... Did a lot of research online before I posted this... Flushing didn't work, Response.End didn't work... It feels like the problem isn't really on the IIS code.. But I couldn't prove it either...

Comment: So what's your .net version that you tried to running on iis7.5 and what's the pipeline mode it defines? When you debugging, where exactly it goes after the calling end to that function without response to end user? Would it be possible you have some httphandler running there but you didn't aware of?

Comment: .net 3.5
Did not change much settings to IIS other than allowing larger file uploads. I guess.. managed pipeline mode?
Used a .ashx handler instead, and still the same result. Occasionally the transfer fails.
Is there something like wireshark but can track packets that flow locally? Or maybe some settings in wireshark that would allow me to track the packets from comes from my locally hosted IIS7.5 to my browser?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18139/discussion-between-simon-wang-and-user1600124)